# How to add multiple controls in a single table column?

Tags: sapui5

I have a small issue. I want to add two controls(`TextView` and `Button`) in a single table column. I have tried concatenation, array type to pass two controls into template but failed. Anyone please help me to solve this.

this is my sample [table](http://jsbin.com/bodeci/2/edit?html,output).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create more complex column templates like this:

```
var nameColumnTemplate = new sap.ui.layout.HorizontalLayout({
  content : [new sap.ui.commons.Button({text : "Click"}), new sap.ui.commons.TextView({text : "{lastName}"})]
});

tbl.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
  label: "Last Name",
  template: nameColumnTemplate
}));
```

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/goboxirika/1/edit?js,output).